# How to fix XHR error using Wavesufer.js on Android external file system with Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, wavesurfer.js

So I'm trying to load a local file into a wavesufer.js waveform. It works totally fine loading files from the device storage on iOS, but I cannot for the life of me get this to work on Android.

According to the Chrome debugger, the GET request is successful, but an "XHR error" is then returned, and the file is not loaded. I've tried many workarounds to no avail. Any help is appreciated.

```
 if(this.platform.is('android')){
          correctedPath = this.file.externalRootDirectory + 'test.3gp';
          this.wavesurfer.load(correctedPath);

}
```

Please note, the file is verified to be at that location, and is playable with the cordova media plugin. I've also tried this without the file tags in the url. This above code works when the file is placed in the www/assets folder and is loaded from there.

Comment: `but an "XHR error" is then returned` - which error? XHR can issue many different errors. The actual error would help in determining what you've done wrong

Comment: `This above code works when the file is placed in the www/assets folder and is loaded from there` - so where is the file when it fails?

Comment: @JaromandaX please see the title or the code... (this.file.externalRootDirectory) The "external file system" generally means on android, the SD card root, or external FS root.

Comment: @JaromandaX

Unfortunately Wavesurfer.js does not specify which error. The only message returned is "XHR error    ". This comes after the XHR Get Request is seen by the chrome debugger. There is no specified error or code listed.